# Best practice on multiple interface barrel

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, model

I am trying to create a library containing all the data models used/transferred from a server API. The model count is very big (almost a new one for each API request).

The typical barrel solution would require an index.ts file exporting all the interfaces one by one. Is it possible however that this list of exports is dynamic, based on e.g. a folder?

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do is to export a file at once if that helps.

```
export * from './somemodule';
```

You can check out the possible ways of exporting in the MDN article [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: This does not help the consumer of the library, since it creates dozens of imports.

Comment: it would go into your index definition file. That way the consumer library only has to import things from there. It's not perfect indeed but it's pretty much all you'd get..